# Started with to low salary - how to approach

Tags: salary

I started a job in a new field and country 2018 and was under the impression I got a fair salary. Quickly I realized I had more experience and more responsibility than colleagues with higher titles than me. I mentioned this to my manager, who agreed but said nothing could be done until my 1-year contract is transformed into a permanent contract.

1 year later I was promoted to a higher position but to my surprise, the salary only increased 3% and people with the same experience had ~15% higher salary. I mentioned this again to my manager who said he would review my salary. I had to wait several months for something to happen because a salary increase is only given once per year. My manager rewarded me 5%, which apparently is the maximum. Still, my salary is not in line with other colleagues. As I am also involved in hiring I know roughly what new joiners get.

I feel like I'm putting lots of energy just to get the average and I have to wait a whole year with unclarity.

I work for a big corporation with 10k+ employees and I know my manager needs to follow certain rules etc. But for me, it feels like I would get a higher salary just by leaving a reapplying for the same position.

How should I approach this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I properly approach my boss if I'm feeling underpaid?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid) Alternatively you may just have to go and find a different job. It's how it is, and why many companies bleed talent because their salary policies are not aligned with reality.

Comment: You need a new job very quickly.

Answer (score 3):

I've been through a very similar situation. It's red tape and politics.

If the company has set a maximum possible raise percentage, there's often little you can do about it. It becomes even harder in large companies where everyone must blindly follow the rules. Even if they make no sense.

I joined a company at a junior salary, and got a small pay rise each year, but not in line with the going rate. When I reached senior, the company was hiring junior developers at the same rate I was being paid, and hiring seniors at 60% higher.

You can explain the situation to your manager, and you can go to your managers manager etc... however, my experience is, if you want the going rate changing job is probably the only way.

> it feels like I would get a higher salary just by leaving a reapplying for the same position

I believe there is nothing stopping you from applying (you don't need to leave your current position first)

Answer (score 1):

What you are experiencing is typical.  There are really only two remedies, and you already tried one and that did not work:

1. Get promoted, or new job title.  Often this will loosen the HR rules, but not always.  Once the rules are off the table the manager is free to give you a large raise.  This did not work for you, so you only have the other option.
2. Move to a new company.  It sounds like you are about 20-25% below market value.  If you are mediocre at your job, just about any company would be happy to get you for 10% below market value, and that would be a massive raise for you.  If you are good to great, they would be happy to have you at market value and that would be even a larger raise.  Your impression of your skill all comes down to your interview skills.

So polish up the resume and move on.  I think you will be very pleased that you did as you seem to have passion for your work and really seem to want to make an impact.

"Actions speak louder than words", and this company has communicated (non-verbally) they are not interested in keeping you as an employee.  So oblige them and move on.

If the situation was reversed and you substantially underperformed you salary for 2 years or more they would fire you.